# Get ViewDataBinding with root view

Tags: android, view, android-databinding

I want to achieve this :

- Create a `ViewDataBinding` by inflating a layout.
- Set a tag to its root view.
- Insert its root view into my layout.
- Later on, call `findViewWithTag()` to retrieve its root view.
- **Getting the `ViewDataBinding` linked to its view.**

But I can't figure out how to achieve the latest step.

This is how my code looks like :

```
MyViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtils.inflate(inflater, R.layout.my_layout, myContainer, false);
View bindingRootView = binding.getRoot();
bindingRootView.setTag("aTag");
myContainer.addView(bindingRootView);

//In another part of the code ...
MyViewDataBinding binding = myContainer.findViewByTag("aTag").getViewDataBinding();
```

But is their something like "getViewDataBinding"?

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find appropriate method in `DataBindingUtil` class. It is called `findBinding(View view)`. It may be needed to cast returned value to your wanted class type.

I'm not sure though whether it's the best architecture. I would be interested if you would give us more context.

Comment: I missed that. My bad, thank you for the quick answer.